# OOP: what goes where and sharing the state between objects

Tags: c#, class, oop

I am diving into the OOP. Still it is hard to understand "HOW TO DO IT". I have the following basic example.

I have a dog and he lives in a house. So here I have two classes.

```
class House
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public House(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

The house has name like "Rex house", "Dog house" or whatever, it does not know anything about the dog, that lives in it.

```
class Dog
{
    private string _name;
    private House _house;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public string House
    {
        get { return _house.Name; }
    }

    public Dog(string name, House house)
    {
        _name = name;
        _house = house;
    }
}
```

The dog, on its birth gets a name and a house.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var house = new House("Dog house");
        var dog = new Dog("Rex", house);
    }
}
```

Lets say that the dog is now big, and you tell him to go to the house, because he was bad.

Should I implement a method called `GoIntoTheHouse()` in Dog class?

But what if other dog taken the house at that moment and the house is full? How and where this state should be saved?

**IN ADDITION TO THIS:**

Maybe there are some sort of source for learning OOP with this kind of real world examples?

Comment: I would personally consider doghouse occupancy a responsibility of the doghouse instead of the dog, so I would make the doghouse have a Dog property instead of the Dog having a House property. If you had several doghouses, you could add them to a collection like a `List<House>`. Then, if a new dog is born and you want to find him a house, you could query the collection for a free doghouse `var house = houses.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Dog == null);`

Comment: I highly recommend reading [The Object Oriented Thought Process](http://amzn.to/1FYj9pM).

Comment: I would like to recommend [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882). Its not so much about OOP but it does give you some rather good ideas about how to structure your code, like which classes should actually have which responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Based strictly on your example, if house can only have one dog at a time but houses can be accessed by any dog you'd want to have Dog as property of House vs. what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in designing your problem, but for your question of "should you implement a method", YES you should because it's already an action/behavior, which for a class (or object should i say) needs to be done whenever it's told to.

O'reilly is a good book for programming. http://www.oreillyschool.com/individual-courses/intro-oop/

But if you don't want to buy a book http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/object-oriented-programming-using-C-Sharp-net/ here's also a good reference